# Sharing authenticated users between Django and django-rest-framework in the same project

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have a Django project that will ultimately consist of three apps. Two of which will be "normal" Django apps, the third is a `djangorestframework` app. I also plan on creating a desktop client for the project at some point.
I want the rest app to be the only entity communicating with the database. Hence I use `requests` to communicate with the rest endpoints from the views of the "normal" Django apps and I will do the same for the desktop client.
 I want all apps to be accessible only for authenticated users, so I'm using Django's authentication backend.

My question is how to pass on the authenticated user/session from the pure Django apps to the rest endpoints when using `requests` in the views.

I managed to authenticate on the rest API using `request`'s `HTTPBasicAuth`, but that requires me to have the user's password at hand in plain text. Sure, I could create a technical user to do these requests. But that would also mean that each and every request would need to go through authentication first and that doesn't feel like the best approach.

I have tried to extract the session cookie from the `request` object that is provided to the views and pass it on through `requests.get`, but did not manage to put it into the `requests.get` call the right way.

As of now, using requests and the established sessions looks like my best bet, especially since that will be the way the desktop client will do things, too. So I'm currently looking for the right way to provide `requests.get` with the session cookie, but I'm certainly open for better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use tokens.

Basically any kind of authentication out of your django project should be managed with secure tokens.

And yes, authentication check should happen everytime you send a request. To make it faster, you can store tokens in memory. (You can use redis or maybe even load your db on memory or ... ) but this is the right and common way to it. Even django does this check everytime using it's builtin functions.

DRF docs recommended some few packages to manage these tokens:

[DRF: Third party packages](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#third-party-packages)

I used [knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox) for many projects and it's pretty good.

Basically to authenticate your users over all of your projects or microservices, you have to take the token from user, set it as header or ... for your request to the main database or authentication project.

Most of the apps use token in headers which you can simply add to all of your `requests` calls:

[Requests docs: Custom Headers](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read about token auth, but didn't feel comfortable using it as I have not yet looked into that enough to fully understand how it works. I'll certainly give it a try. Yes, authentication _checks_ need to happen for every request. What I meant was, that with BasicAuth the user would be (re-)authenticated for every request, whereas with using sessions (or tokens for that matter) it would boil down to checking if the session (or token) provided is valid.

Comment: Well, maybe it doesn't feel comfortable but this is what everyone is using. You can check few APIs for big companies and other open source projects to get a better idea but this is the best way if not the only right way.